# Download config.php

Tags: php, download

I have this code but it keeps downloading `dashboard.php` instead of `../config.php`

```
<?php
$filename = "../config.php";
function forceDownLoad($filename){

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0"); // set expiration time
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filename).";");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));

    @readfile($filename);
    exit(0);
}
forceDownLoad();
?>
```

Why is it downloading `dashboard.php`? I told him to download `config.php` and it keeps on downloading the `dashboard.php`!!

Comment: I see you used the link on my suggestion yesterday.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I did but it's not doing what I want. It now saves the config.php file it saves a part of the site where the file is being saved on.. not the actual config file.

Comment: Look at what [basename($filename) would do to "../config.php";](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) Thats a link to the manual by the way. Not everything comes delivered on a silver platter. When you get code suggestions, you have to look at them and understand the code in them before blindly using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your function which requires a parameter `$filename`. You run the function without giving it the parameter it needs (`forceDownload();`), which makes `$fileName` in your function `NULL`. Hence it'll just catch the root of your website and download that instead. If you have PHP errors on, you will see a notice that the parameter is missing from your function call.

Try this instead:

```
forceDownload($fileName);
```